# Blazor in production: can't find bindings module assembly: System.Private.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Web Assembly project. When I run it on my machine, the project is working fine. So, I use Web Deploy to deploy the project in `Release` in my production server. If I open the page on the production, I have an error

> Uncaught (in promise) Can't find bindings module assembly: System.Private.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript

[image]

The Web Deploy configuration is (all of them are default configuration and there are not other options)

- Configuration: release
- Target framework: net5.0
- Deployment Mode: self-contained
- Target Runtime: browser-wasm

[image]

The root has this files

[image]

and then in the `wwwroot` folder I have all the files

[image]

The `web.config` is the default one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What can I do to fix the problem?

### Update

I decided to update the solution to .NET6. Now, in production ([see here](https://datatable.puresourcecode.com/)) I have another similar error

> Error: Could not find class: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting:EntrypointInvoker in assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly

[image]

Is it only me??

Comment: Do you use vs22 for that? I had similar issues with .net5 (but not with vs19). I solved that by abandoning Publish function in vs and using github actions instead..

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2021. The website is hosted by a provider and I have only Web Deploy to publish the application. Another option is to try to use deploy on file system and them copy but it is not very automated.

Comment: So, try vs19. I may solve the issue..

Comment: I faced the same issue with .NET 5.0.12, but it works for me with .NET 5.0.11 (SDK 5.0.402). Maybe it's a bug introduced with 5.0.12.

Comment: @christianliebel how did you downgrade .NET? I have to uninstall the current one and install the .NET 5.0.11 (SDK 5.0.402)?

Comment: I updated the project to .NET6 and I have another similar error :(

Comment: I downgraded by uninstalling the newer SDK(s). I just upgraded my project to .NET 6 and it also works. Make sure to update your project's target SDK and the Blazor NuGet packages to 6.0.0. Please note that Blazor's service worker may have cached the broken build, so try to reload the page with Ctrl+⇧+R or clear your cache.

Comment: Migrating to .Net 6 worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @christianliebel posted in comments, downgrading to version 5.0.11 seems to be working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to consider. If you have installed Microsoft .NET SDK 6 or 7, it does not matter your target framework (such as 5.0). **dotnet publish** will always use the most recent version of the SDK. This can lead to unexpected problems because you now have incompatible dlls or even dlls you don't need. Try creating a global.json file to indicate the SDK you want to use during publish.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection